# dockerfile and kubernetes jobs ( assistance needed)

Tags: kubernetes, dockerfile, kubernetes-jobs

I have my dockerfile in which i have used postgres:12 image and i modified it using some ddl scripts and then i build this image and i can run the container through docker run command but how i can use Kubernetes jobs to run build image , as I dont have good exp on k8s.

This is my dockerfile here you can see it.

> docker build . -t dockerdb

```
FROM postgres:12 

ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD xyz@123123!233 

ENV POSTGRES_DB test 

ENV POSTGRES_USER test 

COPY ./Scripts /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

How i can customize the below code using the below requirement

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
      kind: Job
      metadata:
        name: job-1
      spec:
        template:
          metadata:
            name: job-1
          spec:
            containers:
            - name: postgres
              image: gcr.io/project/pg_12:dev
              command:
              - /bin/sh
              - -c
              - "not sure what command should i give in last line"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how you are running the docker image

if you are running your docker image without passing any **command** you can directly run the image in Job.

```
docker run <imagename>
```

once your Dockerimage is ready and build you can run it directly

You job will get executed without passing any command

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
      kind: Job
      metadata:
        name: job-1
      spec:
        template:
          metadata:
            name: job-1
          spec:
            containers:
            - name: postgres
              image: gcr.io/project/pg_12:dev
```

if you want to pass any **argument** or **command** that you can pass further

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: <CHANGE IMAGE URL>
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo Hello from the Kubernetes cluster
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Just to update above template is for Cronjob, Cronjob run on specific time.

Comment: Harsh one question , in command section inorder to run dockerimage i can give like kubectl run dockerdb --image=dockerdb or i should i use the option one you have given it will run the image correct ? and i am running docker image after build like this docker run --name postgresdb -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=xyz@123123!233i-d dockerdb

Comment: not sure what actually you are trying to run,looks like you are confuse. you can run and apply the yaml which will create job inside that your image will run.